# Does this mean public beta is going ahead?

Tags: support, public-beta

I noticed this today, I apologise if this has always been there but wanted to confirm so I can rally the community for public beta.

The text in the image says:

> The site's Public Beta will begin soon.

[image: public beta]

Just like to confirm if this is true, and it is a sure thing now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that's the standard text that appears on all private beta sites on area 51.  While this site may make it to public beta, that text is not a definitive confirmation that it will.

Comment: Last announcement was it was extended to october 18th.